# ICP 2.1.0.3 Enterprise Installation fails to resolve IP names/Hostnames

Tags: installation, ibm-cloud-private

I am having the same/similar problem with ICP EE.

[ICP Master Install script - last part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6D05.png)

I have checked everything I can think of:

The master can ping proxy and both workers (by IP address and IP name)
my hosts file contains:

127.0.0.0           localhost

10.10.11.247        icp-master

10.10.11.248        icp-proxy

10.10.11.249        icp-worker1

10.10.11.250        icp-worker2

And my ICP Hosts contains:

[master]

10.10.11.247

[worker]

10.10.11.249

10.10.11.250

[proxy]

10.10.11.248

I run the installer and still get the attached error. I have rerun the installer with -vvv and I still cannot see where the error is.

What really confuses me is that:

TASK [check : Checking Hostname is resolvable]  - Works

TASK [check : Validating Hostname is resolvable] - Fails!

Whats the difference?

Any help would be much appreciated.  Paul B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure the hostname are correct on all ICP nodes. You can scp your /etc/hosts file from master node to all other ICP nodes, thanks.

Comment: Ran 'hostname' on each node, all are correct - subsequently, I took the hyphens out of each hostname, updated all 4 /etc/hosts . Still the same.  There seems a lot of discussions around 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.1.1. My reading is that you need the 127.0.0.1 but NOT the 127.0.1.1.

Comment: It is tricky that your hosts file includes '127.0.0.0 localhost' record. Normally, it should be: 127.0.0.1 localhost

Comment: Sorry, typo - it is 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Also, I have started from scratch, and it seems to be loading up OK. I think the problem was that I copied the public key to /cluster/ssh.key rather than the private.  I will come back with results.... But that could take a while :-)

Comment: That fixed the problem leading me to another one. Will open a new Question for that. Thanks for the help folks

Answer (score -1):

Pls change servers' hostname to validate if it matches with your case.